# How To make some text bold in cell using OpenXml

Tags: c#, openxml-sdk

i have try to make bold the specific text using

```
 Bold fbld = new Bold();
```

but it will make bold hall cell.

[image]

Here in above image there is some bold text into the cell.

How can I do this in OpenXml using C#?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to use separate `Run` elements for the differently styled pieces of text. You can add the bold by creating a `RunProperties` element and adding a `Bold` element to that.

The following code will work on an existing spreadsheet that has no rows (note I haven't added the code for merging as that just adds complication - if you need help with that then please see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37186585/3791802))

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filename, true))
{
    WorkbookPart workBookPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart;

    WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
    WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.First();
    SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().First();

    //create a row
    Row row1 = new Row() { RowIndex = 1U };

    //create a new inline string cell
    Cell cell = new Cell() { CellReference = "A1" };
    cell.DataType = CellValues.InlineString;

    //create a run for the bold text
    Run run1 = new Run();
    run1.Append(new Text("ABC"));
    //create runproperties and append a "Bold" to them
    RunProperties run1Properties = new RunProperties();
    run1Properties.Append(new Bold());
    //set the first runs RunProperties to the RunProperties containing the bold
    run1.RunProperties = run1Properties;
            
    //create a second run for the non-bold text
    Run run2 = new Run();
    run2.Append(new Text(Environment.NewLine + "XYZ") { Space = SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve });

    //create a new inline string and append both runs
    InlineString inlineString = new InlineString();
    inlineString.Append(run1);
    inlineString.Append(run2);

    //append the inlineString to the cell.
    cell.Append(inlineString);

    //append the cell to the row
    row1.Append(cell);

    sheetData.Append(row1);
}
```

Comment: This code works. BUT its causing my excel file to produce a warning regarding Cellinformation. Any idea how to solve that?

Comment: What's the warning?

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but I hope this can be useful to someone reading :)
In general, remember that OpenXml files (xlsx, ppt, word) are only zip files with inside all separated xml files.
When I need something to do I use this workflow:

- Create an excel file with some sample data and save
- Copy it, and apply what you want to do, for example a cell to bold, and save
- Rename both files to .zip and extract them to folders
- Compare diff between folder, I usually use WinMerge for this

Doing like this you can see what has changed when you make a cell to bold, and apply it by code.
It's not a very fast approach, but it works